# How to Loop Through one Range in VBA Excel and Update Another

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

I have a macro that screens cells in a range and when the cell or it's adjacent cell is red or green, it assigns a value to another cell and it's adjacent cell in another worksheet. I have come this far that the first part works, however the second "looping" I can't figure it out myself. In other words, in the code below I want Range ("C1") and Range ("D1") to update to Range ("C2") and Range ("D2") and so on.

```
Sub AutoTrack()

   Dim rng As Range

   Dim cell As Range

   Set rng = Workbooks("Test").Worksheets("Track").Range("I2:I10")

   For Each cell In rng
   If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Or cell.Offset(0, 
    1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then

Worksheets("Result").Range("D1") = 
    WorksheetFunction.MRound(Worksheets("Track").Range("J2").Value + 0.125, 
     0.125)
    Worksheets("Result").Range("C1") = 
    WorksheetFunction.MRound(Worksheets("Result").Range("D1") - 0.75, 0.125)

ElseIf 

   Worksheets("Track").Range("J2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 
   Or Worksheets("Track").Range("I2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 
   0) Then
    Worksheets("Result").Range("C1") = WorksheetFunction.MRound(Worksheets("Track").Range("I2") - 0.125, 0.125)
    Worksheets("Result").Range("D1") = 
    WorksheetFunction.MRound(Worksheets("Result").Range("C1") + 0.75, 0.125)
    End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Does "J2" range also change for each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use offset and a counter which goes up by 1 each iteration of your loop.

If you want the offset to increase whether or not either condition is met then increment `i` outside the If.

```
Sub AutoTrack()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rng = Workbooks("Test").Worksheets("Track").Range("I2:I10")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Or cell.Offset(0, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
        Worksheets("Result").Range("D1").Offset(i) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(cell.Offset(, 1).Value + 0.125, 0.125)
        Worksheets("Result").Range("C1").Offset(i) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(Worksheets("Result").Range("D1").Offset(i) - 0.75, 0.125)
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf cell.Offset(, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Or cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        Worksheets("Result").Range("C1").Offset(i) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(cell - 0.125, 0.125)
        Worksheets("Result").Range("D1").Offset(i) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(Worksheets("Result").Range("C1").Offset(i) + 0.75, 0.125)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: SJR, if `"J2"` and `"I2"` in the first lines of the `IF` and `ELSEIF` statements are static then they are OK. But the ranges in each second line are not static and must increment for each loop,

Comment: @GMalc - I've just amended my code to remove all static references, but it may not be correct as the question is not clear in this regard. Not entirely sure what you mean by "must increment for each loop"?

Comment: SJR, just pointing out that you missed the Offset in  `WorksheetFunction.MRound(Worksheets("Result").Range("C1")'

Comment: @ SJR - Thanks, worked when once I added Offset(i) too at the right handside of the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

try using a counter like this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

i = 2

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

For Each cell In rng

If cell.Value = "A" Then

Worksheets("WS1").Range("B" & i) = "OK"

End If

i = i + 1

Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "J2" and "I2" are static. Since your range is a simple range you can use the row number for each loop, w/ -1, to set the row number on your destination sheet.

```
Sub AutoTrack()
Dim scrws As Worksheet, trgtws As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range

Set scrws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Track")
Set trgtws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")

Set rng = scrws.Range("I2:I10")

    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Or cel.Offset(, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then

            trgtws.Cells(cel.Row - 1, "D") = WorksheetFunction.MRound(scrws.Range("J2").Value + 0.125, 0.125)
            trgtws.Cells(cel.Row - 1, "C") = WorksheetFunction.MRound(trgtws.Cells(cel.Row - 1, "D") - 0.75, 0.125)

        ElseIf scrws.Range("J2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Or scrws.Range("I2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then

            trgtws.Cells(cel.Row - 1, "C") = WorksheetFunction.MRound(scrws.Range("I2") - 0.125, 0.125)
            trgtws.Cells(cel.Row - 1, "D") = WorksheetFunction.MRound(trgtws.Cells(cel.Row - 1, "C") + 0.75, 0.125)

        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```